# setState(): Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get the following warning when I run the code:

> Line 48:  Do not mutate state directly. Use setState() 
>   react/no-direct-mutation-state

This warning refers to these lines of code:

```
updateDelay(prediction_arr,prediction_dep) {
  this.state.chartDataWake = [...this.state.chartDataWake, {wake: this.state.wake===84.73 ? "H" : (this.state.wake===14.78 ? "M" : "L"), delay: prediction_arr}];
  this.state.chartDataTurnaround = [...this.state.chartDataTurnaround, {turnaround: this.state.schedTurnd, delay: prediction_arr}];

  this.setState({
    prediction_arr: prediction_arr,
    prediction_dep: prediction_dep,
    delay_arr_cat: prediction_arr===0 ? "<15" : (prediction_arr===1 ? "[15; 45]" : ">45")
  });
};
```

I understand that I should put all declarations inside `this.setState({`. However it is not clear to me how exactly should I change

```
this.state.chartDataTurnaround = [...this.state.chartDataTurnaround, {turnaround: this.state.schedTurnd, delay: prediction_arr}];
```

in order to be able to compile the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- Don't mutate state directly use setState for that, so remove the first two lines.

2- Because [setState is async](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) and you are updating the state based on previous value, so use `updater function`, means pass a function in setState and use `prevState` value in that function.

Like this:

```
updateDelay(prediction_arr,prediction_dep) {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    prediction_arr: prediction_arr,
    prediction_dep: prediction_dep,
    delay_arr_cat: prediction_arr===0 ? "<15" : (prediction_arr===1 ? "[15; 45]" : ">45"),

    chartDataWake: [
      ...prevState.chartDataWake,
      {wake: prevState.wake===84.73 ? "H" : (prevState.wake===14.78 ? "M" : "L"), delay: prediction_arr}
    ],

    chartDataTurnaround: [
      ...prevState.chartDataTurnaround,
      {turnaround: prevState.schedTurnd, delay: prediction_arr}
    ]
  }));
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Never modify the state using `this.state.YOUR_VARIABLE = something`

If you want, and seen from the snippet that you do,
to copy the prevState into your new state as well as be able to add new elements to it, you should use Object Cloning to first copy the previous state and then add as many more elements you want to this copy.

```
updateDelay(prediction_arr, prediction_dep) {
 const newChartDataWake = [...this.state.chartDataWake, {
  wake: this.state.wake === 84.73 ? "H" : (this.state.wake === 14.78 ? "M" : "L"),
  delay: prediction_arr
 }];

 const newChartDataTurnaround = [...prevState.chartDataTurnaround, {
  turnaround: prevState.schedTurnd,
  delay: prediction_arr
 }]



 this.setState(prevState => {
  return {
   chartDataWake: newChartDataWake
   chartDataTurnaround: newChartDataTurnaround
   prediction_arr: prediction_arr,
   prediction_dep: prediction_dep,
   delay_arr_cat: prediction_arr === 0 ? "<15" : (prediction_arr === 1 ? "[15; 45]" : ">45")
  }
 });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the callback for setState which gets previous State as an argument.

```
this.setState((prevState,props) => 
({
   chartDataWake:[...prevState.chartDataWake, {wake: prevState.wake===84.73 
       ? "H" : (prevState.wake===14.78 ? "M" : "L"), delay: prediction_arr}],
   chartDataTurnaround = [...prevState.chartDataTurnaround, {turnaround: 
      prevState.schedTurnd, delay: prediction_arr}],
   prediction_arr: prediction_arr,
   prediction_dep: prediction_dep,
   delay_arr_cat: prediction_arr===0 ? "<15" : (prediction_arr===1 ? "[15; 
      45]" : ">45")
})
```